# The couchdb equivalent of a relational database model

Tags: mysql, database, couchdb

I am new at the use of couchdb, but I have a background in backend programming and relational databases.

I want to "migrate my knowledge" from mySQL to CouchDB. Although I found a lot of information about installation and getting started tutorials, I am having trouble to actually "translate" a relational model to the CouchDB document storage. And I know, I need to completely reset my way of thinking...

I want to get into this matter the best way possible, so I started a basic exercise. I have a simple relational model from an actual in use software application. For simplicity purposes, I toned down the number of fields.

**Case**

We have a stack of cards. Each card has its own properties (id, name, imgpath, etc). Each user can have a random collection of cards picked from the stack in its own cards collection.

**MySQL**

In mySQL there are 3 tables:

- Users [id, name, password]
- Cards [id, name, value1, value2, imgpath, etc]
- UserCards [userid, cardid]

*Other relevant information:*

- We have more than 10k users and growing.
- It's for a mobile app, so speed is very much relevant.
- We (now) use a different db.scheme per user, each assigned their own userrights per scheme. (Once a decision made regarding security).

**CouchDB Questions**

- What is the most efficient way of storing the users and cards in the CouchDB Document model? (So how do I "translate" the tables?)
- Is it efficient/more secure to create a database/scheme for each of the users or just store it all in 1 database?

---

Obviously there are a lot more tables and fields involved in the real life application itself, but I just need a solid starting point and I, hopefully, can go from there.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Since you clearly have a relational model, why do you want to use a non-relational store for them? Not because the notion that it would be faster?

Comment: Well, yes I have the notion it will be faster? Is that an incorrect assumption? And 2nd we want to be able to use cloud storage and easily expand servers when needed...

Comment: Considering that relational databases are designed to handle relational data, I would say trying to make a document storage behave like one and be faster is the wrong way. It will probably cause more problems than it will solve. And if MySQL would be too slow, there are better alternatives available. Also there are lots of providers for relational database services online, so you can host it "in the cloud" without any problems.

Comment: Well u got me rethinking the whole approuch now. What is a good thing I guess. Thank you. Do you happen to know of any good articles to underline your statement? Because I have read many and somehow came to the conclusion this was the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the most efficient way of storing the users and cards in the CouchDB Document model? (So how do I "translate" the tables?)

- store User docs in the built-in `_users` db
- store cards in a separate bucket (db)
- implement the mapping cards2user as view

> Is it efficient/more secure to create a database/scheme for each of the users or just store it all in 1 database?

It depends on the application needs:

If you need to control read access to card you will need the db-per-user approach.

If you just need to control write access one db with all cards is my recommendation.

User accounts are stored in the users db un both cases.

Comment: _users is a system table right? Specifically for use with the db itself? We can just use (abuse) it to store our application specific users?

Comment: Its not an abuse - its the only db with special read access rights which keeping your users data confidential.